# WaitKey along with pthreads

Tags: opencv, pthreads

I have a code that requires me to compute homography for each frame of a video and process the white density of the resultant frame. I am using threads for reading multiple frames and passing them to `pthread_create`.

I was initially taking mouse input for the points which required `WaitKey` **before computing the homography**. This code had a visible difference in runtime with the increase in the number of threads used.

But when I changed the code to a fixed set of points (thus removing the need for `WaitKey`), the runtime became constant irrespective of the number of threads used.

Old code:

```
ThreadArgs::corners = getCorners(ThreadArgs::refFrame, "Select corners"); // getCorners uses WaitKey
if (ThreadArgs::corners.size() != 4)
{
    cerr << "Escape key pressed, aborting execution\n";
    return 0;
}
ThreadArgs::cornersMap = findMap(ThreadArgs::corners);
warpAndCrop(ThreadArgs::refFrame, ThreadArgs::corners, ThreadArgs::cornersMap);
// this is where I started my clock
```

New code:

```
ThreadArgs::corners = vector<Point2f>({{998, 222}, {1268, 223}, {1520, 1015}, {384, 1015}});
ThreadArgs::cornersMap = findMap(ThreadArgs::corners);
warpAndCrop(ThreadArgs::refFrame, ThreadArgs::corners, ThreadArgs::cornersMap);
// this is where I start my clock
```

What I fail to understand is that how is something that is seemingly unrelated causing such a drastic change in the runtime analysis?

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Updated now. Please check.

Comment: That's quite impossible to answer without seeing the affected code.

Comment: I didn't get you. This is the only modification in the complete file (before this, there is only user input and defining variables). The only difference is that I was taking user input for points in the original code, and in the second code, I hardcoded the same values.